# Ruby - how to get values from an array which has other arrays and hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have data in this format:

```
{"values"=>
[
{"updateKey"=>"UNIU-16268324-5608633092144111616-SHARE", 
"updateComments"=>{"_start"=>1, 
"values"=>[{"comment"=>"Sample test this is mike testing.", 
  "person"=>{"siteStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=116654056&authToken=xVLh&authType=name&trk=api*a140290*s148640*"}, 
  "lastName"=>"DeLorenzo", 
  "headline"=>"--", 
  "id"=>"QM86-RIKjb", 
  "pictureUrl"=>"http://media.linkedin.com/mpr/mprx/0_OurBLnHMma92b4U4pecXLq2MuW8aFOo4ywXHLqEbPuNO4sjZtEhUwNOWCFhAkJIq07-WoP4V_Zqg", "firstName"=>"Jennifer", 
  "apiStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/QM86-RIKjb",     "headers"=>{"values"=>
[{"name"=>"x-li-auth-token", 
"value"=>"name:xVLh"}], 
"_total"=>1}}}, 
"timestamp"=>1337202768000, 
"sequenceNumber"=>1, 
"id"=>80942976}, 
{"comment"=>"123", 
"person"=>{"siteStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=70292133&authToken=wEAo&authType=name&trk=api*a140290*s148640*"}, "lastName"=>"Kartsovnyk", "headline"=>"Snr Software Developer", "id"=>"7-32mNn-Ob", "pictureUrl"=>"http://media.linkedin.com/mpr/mprx/0_xjj5WPXU6fCjCExLjUa9WA69XWNS
```

What I am trying to do is to loop through the updateComments and get each "id" attribute for that user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if linked_in_updates.values.updateComments.is_a?(Hash)   
  linked_in_updates.each { |key, value|
    some_value = key
  }
end
```

I am trying to extract the hash which is the updateComments with this: linked_in_updates.values.updateComments but I get the error like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `updateComments' for #<Array:0x13228fc20>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That [looks like JSON](http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-json.html) with literal `\n` rather than linebreaks

Comment: @Michael would that make an impact on how I extract the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
linked_in_updates.values.updateComments.is_a?(Hash)
```

with

```
linked_in_updates.values[0]['updateComments'].is_a?(Hash)
```

Comment: thanks! Could you please exaplain to me why the syntax is values[0]['updateComments'] ? I am not sure how it was a 2-d array.  I'll accept the answer when SO allows me.

Comment: btw also I get the error: TypeError: can't convert String into Integer after I try your suggestions.

Comment: add `Rails.logger.info linked_in_updates.values[0]` before `if linked_in_updates.values.updateComments.is_a?(Hash)` then run `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: Actually that is the line that gives the error: TypeError: can't convert Array into String :)

Comment: I just updated the data that comes in. Maybe it makes a difference.

Comment: It's not that it's a 2d array, it's that the 0th element of the array is a hash, and that hash is then addressed with the key `updateComments`.